# How to make text-rects appear one after another, after a delay in pygame

Tags: python, text, time, pygame, blit

hoping to get some help regarding blitting text-rects in a sequence, a small delay of about a second between them. I've managed to get pretty close however my most recent attempt repeats the process of blitting my three lines of text over and over. I can't for the life of my figure out how to have these three lines blit to the screen in order, and then stop.

I have included an example of this part of my code, any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def Title_Screen():
    while True:
        TitleScreen_MOUSE_POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Background
        SCREEN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Title
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        SCREEN.blit(TitleScreen1_TEXT, TitleScreen1_RECT)
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        SCREEN.blit(TitleScreen2_TEXT, TitleScreen2_RECT)
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        SCREEN.blit(TitleScreen3_TEXT, TitleScreen3_RECT)

        # Press Any Key To Continue
        SCREEN.blit(PressKeyText, PressKeyRect)
        pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                Main_menu()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()          
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You're blitting the images inside a `while True` loop, which is an infinite loop. That's why the process is being repeated over and over again.

Comment: Of course it was such an easy fix haha. Have now moved the blit functions out of the while true loop, leaving only the events in that loop. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the state of the resources outside of the main loop.

In the example below, we use a list of font-images to hold what-to-paint.  But the control of *which* image to paint is advanced with a timer function.

Of course, there's lots of different ways to do this.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT= 300

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Title Screen" )

                
font  = pygame.font.Font( None, 50 )
text1 = font.render( "The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea", 1, WHITE)
text2 = font.render( "  In a beautiful pea-green boat,", 1, WHITE)
text3 = font.render( "They took some honey, and plenty of money,", 1, WHITE)
text4 = font.render( "  Wrapped up in a five-pound note.", 1, WHITE)
title_lines = [ text1, text2, text3, text4 ]

title_delay     = 2000  # Milliseconds between title advances
title_count     = 4     # How many titles are in the animation
title_index     = 0     # what is the currently displayed title
title_next_time = title_delay  # clock starts at 0, time for first title


while True:
    clock = pygame.time.get_ticks()   # time now

    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    # paint the screen
    screen.fill( BLACK )  # paint it black

    # Write the current title, unless we've seen them all
    if ( title_index < title_count ):
        screen.blit( title_lines[ title_index ], ( 10, 10 ) )

        # Is it time to update to the next title?
        if ( clock > title_next_time ):
            title_next_time = clock + title_delay  # some seconds in the future
            title_index += 1 # advance to next title-image

    pygame.display.flip()
```